# How can I change tag separator from "," to "+"?

Tags: 7, meta-tags

I want to change tag separator in a Term reference field of my content type (using Autocomplete term widget (tagging)) from "," to "+" or maybe something else (in Drupal 7) because this field needs to be filled in Persian.
What shoud I do ?
thanks.

Comment: You question lacks context.

Comment: Please refer to the faq option in the top menu to find more about asking questions.  It is unclear where you are trying to apply this change and why, so it is not clear to a responder how to answer.  You can edit and expand upon your question to clarify.

Comment: Is that clear enough now?

Comment: Now I believe I understand the question. However, I prefer not to help people do "wrong" things, and find it hard to imagine the circumstances in which this is a good idea.

Comment: @letharion Can you provide an answer re: why it is wrong?

Comment: @Sheshkovsky Out of curiosity, why can't you use the comma in Persian?

Comment: because "," is "،" in persian so users should change their keyboard format, and as long as this field could fill with both English ang Persian words, I need a character which is same in these languages.

Comment: @Ashlar, When I don't understand _why_ people are doing what they are doing, I suspect they are going about the actual problem in the wrong way. _Now_ that have some more information, I can tell you that this is a known problem. [Issue here](http://drupal.org/node/582534). While you can manipulate the form itself, as suggested below, the real solution is in pushing that issue. Engage in [office hours](http://drupal.org/node/1242856) and the experienced core maintainers will help you fix the problem for real instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideal answer of my question according to [this issue](http://drupal.org/node/582534) is: In drupal/include/common.inc file, change the line `$regexp = '%(?:^|,\ *)("(?>[^"]*)(?>""[^"]* )*"|(?: [^",]*))%x';` to  `$regexp = '%(?:^|,|،|\ *)("(?>[^"]*)(?>""[^"]* )*"|(?: [^",|،|]*))%xu';`.

Now both English and Persian comma is available for separator, and I will not worry about changing keyboard language or not!

Answer (score 1):

you can use a [hook_form_FORM_ID_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/7). I used this validation to make sure users use commas instead of spaces:

```
function MYMODUDLE_form_FORM_ID_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
 $form['#validate'][] = 'custom_form_validate';
}


function custom_form_validate($form, &$form_state) {
  $tags = $form_state['values']['field_MYNAME_tags']['und'];
  foreach ($tags as $tag) {
    if ((strlen($tag['name']) > 15) || (substr_count($tag['name'], ' ') > 1)) {
      form_set_error('field_MYNAME_tags', 'Please enter tags separated by commas');
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Two notes for this regex fixed:
At first you should change common.inc file unicode to utf-8;
Then remember that when you upgrade your drupal core, you sholud redo this change in common.inc file again.

Answer (score 0):

Your ultimate solution is `autocomplete deluxe` module. You can get from its [project page](https://www.drupal.org/project/autocomplete_deluxe)

[image]